# Finding the right input shape to get specific output shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras, input, conv-neural-network

I would like to use EfficicentNet model (https://keras.io/api/applications/efficientnet/#efficientnetb0-function) after a so called ST layer, which was used in this paper (http://www.ee.iisc.ac.in/people/faculty/soma.biswas/Papers/jain_icgvip2016_alpr.pdf, see Table 4) to recognize license plates with a segmentation-free approach. So, the ST layer, which is defined below is the first layer in my network and afterwards EfficientNetB0 would follow. The default input shape in EfficientNetB0 is `(224, 224, 3)`. Because of that I am now looking for the input shape of my images in the ST layer and would like to derive `x` in the shape `(x, x, 3)`.

I defined this model:

```
def create_ST_layer(input_shape = (x, x, 3)):
    input_img = Input(shape=input_shape)
    model = Conv2D(48, kernel_size=(5, 5), input_shape = input_shape, strides = (1, 1))(input_img)
    model = Activation("relu") (model)
    model = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides = (2, 2))(model)
    model = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides = (1, 1))(model)
    model = Activation("relu") (model)
    model = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides = (2, 2))(model)
    model = Dense(50)(model)
    model = Activation("relu")(model)
    output = Dense(6)(model)
    output = Reshape((224, 224, 3))(output)
    model = Model(input_img, output)

    return model
```

I now would like to find the values `(x, x, 3)` for the input_shape to get an output of `(224, 224, 3)`. How would you proceed? Including `padding=same` at the `Conv2D` layers is okay too.

Comment: Your question is too ambigious. Could you kindly explain more?

Comment: Is your code for ST layer correct? Particularly the output of final Dense layer is `6` & couldn't be converted into `224x224x3` shape. And as far as I know, I doubt you could directly apply `Dense` layer to the output of `MaxPool` directly before applying something like Flatten, GlobalAveragePooling, etc